# How many rep to remove "new contributor" tag?

Tags: support, new-users

I'm relatively new to SE, and I have 185 reputation on the main worldbuilding exchange. I wanted to know: Is the "new contributor" thing tied to reputation? And if so, how much do I need to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the official release about the "New Contributor" flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator),

> tl;dr;: Folks will see an indicator when they go to interact with new contributors (visible for a week following their first post) letting them know that the person is new. A handy link to our Code of Conduct will be in the notification for reference.

So, theoretically, one week following your first post. You'll notice as of today (April 7, 2021) that it's gone from your main site listings. It's still here on Meta because Meta and Main are always treated separately. I expect the "new contributor" flag to disappear here on Meta by April 15th.